# Cucumber wait for promise to finish

Tags: node.js, cucumber, nightwatch.js

I´m having trouble with Cucumber and  Nightwatch.js. In one of my features, on the first step I make a POST request to obtain an id and then I use that Id into the URL I need to navigate. The problem im having is that by the time I get the reponse I´m on another step so the test fails becuase the item i´m trying to look it isn´t there. Here is the a snipplet of the steps I was taking about.

```
    Given(/^I make a post request and retreive the Id i got the page + id$/, () => {
  //I make the post request 
  var transactionIdPromise = utils.getTransactionId(1);
  var url = "";

  transactionIdPromise.getBody('utf8').then(JSON.parse).done(function (result) {
      var id = result.transaction_id;
      url = "https://mywebpage.com:8443/" + id;
      return client.url(url)
  });
});

//request that returns id
var getTransactionId = function (user) {
        return request('POST', 'http://localhost:8888/internal/retreive_transaction/?', {json: {user_id: user, type: 'UNIQUENESS', info: '{"person_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}'}});
    };
```

My question is how can I make it wait for the request to finish before moving into the next step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make Cucumber.js to wait for the promise to be resolved you have to return it as the result of the step definition. So you need to put a `return` before `transactionIdPromise.getBody...`

Comment: that does the trick! but now whats happening is that my client.url isnt navigating to the page inmediatly

Comment: finally found an answer for 4 hrs of research.. Thanks a lot.. @musci96 Would you please explain why this works?